# Merging two Sass files

Tags: merge, sass

I'm wanting to on the fly merge two sass files together, so for instance:

If I have

```
.some-class
  color: white
```

and

```
.some-class
  background-color: red
```

then the end result would be

```
.some-class
  color: white
  background-color: red
```

Does anyone know of a tool / library that can do this kind of thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's say you have 2 files:

**a.scss**

```
div{
    font-size: 42px;
}
```

and

**b.scss**

```
@import "a.scss";
div{
    color: red;
}
```

First you should run `sass b.scss e.css` it will output:

**e.css**

```
div {
  font-size: 42px; }

div {
  color: red; }
```

Then `sass-convert e.css e.sass` and you will get:

**e.sass**

```
div
  font-size: 42px
  color: red
```

Comment: run where? In the terminal?

Answer (score 1):

You can use *node-sass*: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass
Example:

```
command: node-sass src/css -o dest
```

css all file merge in dest file.