# CSS automated merge between two similar files

Tags: css, merge, sass, duplicates

I would love some advice on handling 2 large (7k+ lines) CSS files. I want to refactor these eventually, but before this point I would like to merge the two.

They're not carbon copies of each other but they're both incredibly similar with lots of duplicated code if both inserted.

Is there a quick way of instantly merging the two files to produced one concatenated file that includes all the individual CSS.

---

For example combine file 1

```
.Duplicate-class-1 {
    background: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
 .Duplicate-class-2 {
    background: blue;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
.Unique-class-1{
    background: purple;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

With file 2

```
.Duplicate-class-1 {
    background: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
 .Duplicate-class-2 {
    background: blue;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
.Unique-class-2{
    background: green;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

And result in

```
.Duplicate-class-1 {
    background: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
 .Duplicate-class-2 {
    background: blue;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
.Unique-class-1{
    background: purple;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
.Unique-class-2{
    background: green;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: i don't think there is possible way to do this may be some online tools will help

Comment: You could compare the files in Notepad++ using the TextFX plugin. It will not be anything automated though.

Comment: You'll need a built tool like [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/). There are many plugins for tasks like these, such as [gulp-css-purge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-css-purge) which removes duplicate CSS.

Comment: The answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25444121/3162554) could help.